ERC6551 and module style
I would use ERC6551 to introduce accounts as NFTs into the game.
I believe that adding a modular style to the account contraption would make it an extensible contraption.
However, in contrast to account abstraction, we noticed that examples of the modular style of ERC6551 are extremely hard to find, both on github and anywhere else. perhaps the modular style of ERC6551 is not a valid approach?

I have found the following implementations of it:

Tokenbound SDK
Thirdweb's Custom Smart Accounts
Next.js Frontend

Hope it helps.
